# What tpl or php file calls/loads CRM/UF/Page/Group.tpl for the Profiles page?

Tags: profile, joomla, templates, debugging

I trying to debug my civicrm backend Profiles page on Joomla.  Could someone backtrace the templates/CRM/UF/Page/Group.tpl when the the Profiles page is loaded?  I believe the Profiles page loads the templates/CRM/UF/Page/Group.tpl

For some reason, my setup does not load the templates/CRM/UF/Page/Group.tpl and I am unable to find the tpl or php page that is suppose to load the Group.tpl.

Answer (score 1):

For the Profiles page, the templates/CRM/common/joomla.tpl template loads the Group.tpl file.  Since the production website was malfunctioning, I had to install a local copy in order to adequately debug.